# How can I combine a React element and text inside a ternary?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, ternary

Normally if you have something like:

```
<SomeComponent foo={bar} />
```

you can make it optional by using a ternary:

```
{bar ? <SomeComponent foo={bar} /> : null}
```

But what if the block you are starting with contains a component plus some text (a single space) and a variable, e.g.:

```
<SomeComponent foo={bar} /> {foobar}
```

Wrapping it in parentheses won't work:

```
{bar ? (<SomeComponent foo={bar} /> {foobar}) : null}
```

and in fact the only way I found to make it work was to wrap everything in another element:

```
{bar ? <span><SomeComponent foo={bar} /> {foobar}</span> : null}
```

Is there any other way to tell React that:

```
<SomeComponent foo={bar} /> {foobar}
```

is a discrete chunk, so that I can use it in a ternary (inside JS, not JSX, logic) ... without adding meaningless wrapper elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There used to be two suboptimal ways to achieve this:

1. Using an array, which requires adding keys to React elements:

   ```
   {bar ? [<SomeComponent key="1" foo={bar} />, " ", foobar] : null}
   ```
2. Creating a [wrapper component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48132836/1247274), like @margaretkru suggested.

But with React 16.2.0+ you can use [improved fragments](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html):

```
{bar ? <React.Fragment><SomeComponent foo={bar} /> {foobar}</React.Fragment> : null}
```

or, even better, you can use the shorthand syntax:

```
{bar ? <><SomeComponent foo={bar} /> {foobar}</> : null}
```

Fragments won't produce an additional container element.

Comment: wow, that's cool. I thought you could only use fragments when returning from `render`, but now when I think about it, it shouldn't matter, it is all `jsx` anyway :)

Comment: Technically `<>` is still a wrapper, but since I suspect that a truly wrapper-less solution doesn't exist (and since it's not truly "meaningless", as it is defining a fragment), this seems like the best viable option ... and also, like @margaretkru said, it's pretty cool :)

Comment: Yeah, it's semantically a wrapper, but doesn't render as one. I updated my answer for older React versions. @margaretkru I linked to your very elegant solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could define a small component that would act as a wrapper but won't render any markup, but it technically is still a wrapper. I use this approach by defining `Aux` component:

```
const Aux = (props) => (props.children);
```

Then you can do:

```
{bar ? <Aux><SomeComponent foo={bar} /> {foobar}</Aux> : null}
```

This at least avoids unnecessary markup in the resulting `html` which might be crucial for styling purposes, if you are using `flex-box` for example.